# What is the purpose of the AuthenticatorInterface::supports() method?

Tags: symfony, symfony-security, symfony-flex, symfony4

In Symfony 4, the `AuthenticatorInterface::supports()` method has the following comment:

```
interface AuthenticatorInterface extends AuthenticationEntryPointInterface
{
    /**
     * Does the authenticator support the given Request?
     *
     * If this returns false, the authenticator will be skipped.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function supports(Request $request);
```

I find the phrasing confusing. My first instinct when I tried implementing this was to return true if the request contains a `username` and `password` field, but then I remembered that all the requests I am receiving are getting authenticated, even if i am not using the login form.

Is the `supports()` method a way to override the `security.firewalls.myFirewall.pattern` argument? Is it a thing that handles the flow between multiple authenticators?

How should I use this interface?

Answer (score 2):

I agree this feature isn't that well documented (yet). The only thing I can find is this:

[How to Create a Custom Authentication System with Guard](https://symfony.com/doc/master/security/guard_authentication.html)

> **supports(Request $request)**
>
> This will be called on every request and
> your job is to decide if the authenticator should be used for this
> request (return true) or if it should be skipped (return false).

For example: you can use the `Request` to check if it is a XMLHttpRequest (AJAX), so you can have dedicated `AjaxAuthenticator`.

A similar feature (`VoterInterface::support()`) is documented at [How to Use Voters to Check User Permissions](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html).

Comment: After reading the source code a bit more, that's my guess as well. It looks like it's used when we are having multiple authenticators inside a specific firewall

Comment: After digging up the docs a bit more, I found this: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-guard-authentication-improvements

This makes it sound like we should return true only when the user submits the login form.

Comment: You should have written a response with your comment's content. I did not see them before writing mine, but you had a good explanation !

Answer (score 0):

This interface comes in replacement of `GuardAuthenticationInterface` that is deprecated in Symfony 3.4, and removed from Symfony 3.4.

This difference is that the former `GuardAuthenticationInterface` only defined a `getCredentials` method that returns `NULL` or any form of credentials. In some cases there are many ways to get the credentials for an authenticator, the `getCredentials` method was processed any way, until something is returned, or end without returning anything (that is almost equivalent to a null return).

When you use multiple authenticators, you don't want to wait each one to return nothing to pass to the following one. So that this `supports` method appeared in order to return if, yes or no, the authenticator `getCredentials` method must be called. Note that in the new `AuthenticationInterface`, `getCredentials` method is always supposed to return something.

Here is [an article from Symfony's blog that describes the move](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-guard-authentication-improvements)